# Changing class breaks in ArcGIS without resetting whole symbology?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology

For the purposes of this map, I have a raster with very specific class breaks with custom colors for each class.

Sometimes for various reasons the class breaks have to be adjusted slightly based on new input.

However changing the classification breaks completely resets everything.

The colors and labels will all be reset and have to be redone manually.

Comment: Have you tried making a custom ramp?  See https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/04/20/create-a-custom-color-ramp/

Comment: Using preset colors and setting a discrete color ramp does work. Luckily as I have 7 classes and as there's 13 slots in the preset properties which ArcMap doesn't seem to let you change, I can set each two consecutive colors the same, and the last category the 7th color. I could see it getting tricky with different numbers of classes (esp. >13), but this "divides" into my 7 classes well enough for me.

Comment: Actually could use multiple preset color ramps in a single color ramp style, either a solid color each or try to split them in 2-3 classes or more. Bit of work to make sure it divides right over your classes but it would work for any # of classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Style Manager (Customize > Style Manager) create a custom 'Multi-part Color Ramp', with 7 parts (or however many parts you need).

Make each of those 7 parts an 'Algorithmic Color Ramp' and set them to a single color.  You'll then end up with a discrete 7 part color ramp that won't change when you update your values (unless you add or remove breaks).

Inside Multi-Part color ramp:
[image]

End result:
[image]